# Cross-region event-driven architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, distributed-systems, disaster-recovery-plans

My company use AWS for a few event-driven apps. The catch is that all events are either time-based (9pm daily, month-end, quarter-end, etc.) or S3-based (put object, deleted object, etc.).

The setup looks like this:

```
               Pattern                     Target
               -------                     ------
Event Rule 1   9pm daily                   ECS Cluster 1
Event Rule 2   File dropped to S3 bucket   ECS Cluster 2
```

The event rules and targets all live in the same AWS region. How can I make this cross-regional? The events should be produced and processed if one region is unavailable. The ECS clusters are already available in both Primary and Secondary regions.